# Single flight multiple flight numbers?

Tags: air-travel, factoids, code-share

Is it possible for a single flight to have multiple flight numbers?

[image]

Comment: Yes, if it is subject to a [Codeshare agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeshare_agreement) between the airlines.

Comment: Yes, but there might be only one of the flight numbers shown on the arrivals screen in the terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the same flight can have multiple flight codes if it is run in [codeshare agreement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeshare_agreement) between multiple airlines.  Quoting from the linked page:

> Typically, a flight is operated by one airline (technically called an "administrating carrier"[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeshare_agreement)) while seats are sold for the flight by all cooperating airlines using their own designator and flight number.

Hence why the flight can have as many codes as there are airlines selling seats on it.

In your example, [the flight is operated by Air France](https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/AF/1487) in codeshare with Flybe, Alitalia, and many more.

Comment: Note that even though it’s officially an “administrating carrier”, it is more commonly known as the “operating carrier”.

Comment: At least in the past, it was also the case that an alternative flight number might be assigned if it could be booked as a direct flight with change of gauge or as a connecting flight, on the same aircraft. I remember going through the paces with pre-merger United back in the day. As a humble 1P I had a chance of an upgrade clearing SFO-KIX, but not IAD-SFO (weirdly enough), and wanted them to re-issue my ticket as the connection rather than the direct. Plus, it would net 900 more miles that way.